# Getting View from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Programatically I have a `RelativeLayout` and `TextView` (called title) within it defined as follows:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parameters_title = 
      new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
title.setLayoutParams(parameters_title);
layout.addView(title,parameters_title);
```

I intend to add more `textviews` and `buttons` later. But for now, I want to "convert" (I am not sure how to put it into words) the `RelativeLayout` into a `View` in order to put it into `WindowManager`. I was trying to use `LayoutInflater` like this but it wouldn't work

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
       (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
myView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null );
```

then the goal is to put `myView` into `WindowManger` through `addView`. How can I get a `View` from my `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: What you want to do exactly ?

Comment: ok haha ultimate goal is to create a Layout programatically without having the XML file then add that layout to WindowManager

Comment: `setContentView(myView);`

Comment: Actually I just found out I can put my RelativeLayout directly into the WindowManager through .addView()

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684275/adding-dynamic-view-using-windowmanager-addview)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by getChildAt but you will have to keep the position of the view you want to get from layout. To avoid this you can set an id for your view and get the view with findViewById(). If you inflate a view from xml you will get the same views as xml. if you add some new views to the relativeLayout it will not effect the view you inflate from the xml.

when you  are  adding the view:

```
 myView.setId(id);
 layout.addView(myView);
```

when you are retrieving

```
 View myView = layout.findViewById(id);
```